# Promisifying Zookeeper's multiple callback function

Tags: javascript, promise, apache-zookeeper, bluebird

Zookeeper provides a `getChildren` method that takes in the path of the node and returns the children of that node in a callback. It also sets a watch during the process and calls the watcher callback when a watch is triggered

```
getChildren(path, function(err,event){
        //this is the watcher callback
    },
    function(err,children,stats){
        //children callback
    }
)
```

So if I use the bluebird's `Promise.promisify` to promisify this function. How do I know that the promise this function is returning is the watcher or the children ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the `getChildren()` interface correctly, the last callback is designed to be called once with the list of child objects.  The first callback is a watcher callback that may be called an indefinite number of times to notify you of various changes occurring.

Given that, the last callback could fit with a promise.  The first callback cannot and must remain a callback.  In addition, the second callback is returning multiple results (which does not fit perfectly with promises) so you have to make allowances for that too using `multiArgs` and `.spread`.

So, you could do something like this:

```
let getChildrenP = Promise.promisify(getChildren, {multiArgs: true});

getChildrenP(path, function(err, event) {
    // watcher event occurred here
    // this may get called multiple times
}).spread(function(children, stats) {
    // children are available now
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```